# How to add calendar and announcement list to my custom web template?

Tags: web-template

I am using sharepoint 2010 and VS2010.

I have implemented this tutorial for creating a custom web template:

http://usmanmughal.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/how-to-create-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010-using-feature/

Now I would like to add the calendar and announcements list to the home page. Where and how do I do this on my web template files like below:

1. defaultdws.aspx
2. default.aspx
3. ONET.xml
4. elements.xml

What to do in which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify Onet.xml file,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474369(v=office.12).aspx

If you go through article link I given above you will figure out that in Onet.xml file you need to add

```
<ListTemplates>
  <ListTemplate .. tag for calendar list and then />
  <ListTemplate .. tag for calendar list and then />
</ListTemplates>
```

You will need to change [list template type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd958106%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for calendar and annoucement in list template, I will let you do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented the 2 listtemplates like in this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588362%28v=office.11%29.aspx. But where can I implement it on the home page in some webpartzone?